# Similar cython issue installing python packages on centos6.6

Tags: python, pip, cython, centos6

I am trying to install the following python packages from pypi (os: centos6.6):

```
pip install -i https://pypi.python.org/pypi pymssql
pip install -i https://pypi.python.org/pypi pyodbc
pip install -i https://pypi.python.org/pypi PySide
```

but none of the installs work and they all seem to have a common issue. Lets look at each error one by one:

Let's start with pymssql:

```
[root@8e6379e8595f /]# pip install pymssql
Collecting pymssql
Downloading http://mypiprepo-au/mypiprepo/pymssql/pymssql-2.1.1.zip (2.3MB)
100% |ââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââ| 2.3MB 13.2MB/s
Installing collected packages: pymssql
  Running setup.py install for pymssql ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-Msb2ws/pymssql/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Me_cOI-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
setup.py: platform.system() => 'Linux'
setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('64bit', '')
setup.py: platform.linux_distribution() => ('CentOS', '6.6', 'Final')
setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('glibc', '2.3')
setup.py: Using bundled FreeTDS in /tmp/pip-build-Msb2ws/pymssql/freetds/nix_64
setup.py: include_dirs = ['/tmp/pip-build-Msb2ws/pymssql/freetds/nix_64/include', '/usr/local/include']
setup.py: library_dirs = ['/tmp/pip-build-Msb2ws/pymssql/freetds/nix_64/lib', '/usr/local/lib']
running install
running build
running build_ext
cythoning _mssql.pyx to _mssql.c

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
            return uuid.UUID(bytes_le=(<char *>data)[:length])

        else:
            return (<char *>data)[:length]

    cdef int convert_python_value(self, object value, BYTE **dbValue,
        ^
------------------------------------------------------------

_mssql.pyx:821:9: Signature not compatible with previous declaration

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    cdef object msghandler

    cpdef cancel(self)
    cdef void clear_metadata(self)
    cdef object convert_db_value(self, BYTE *, int, int)
    cdef int convert_python_value(self, object value, BYTE **, int*, int*) except -1
                                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

_mssql.pxd:38:33: Previous declaration is here
building '_mssql' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-build-Msb2ws/pymssql/freetds/nix_64/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c _mssql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mssql.o -DMSDBLIB
_mssql.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-Msb2ws/pymssql/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Me_cOI-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Msb2ws/pymssql
```

pyodbc:

```
Step 13 : RUN pip install -i https://pypi.python.org/pypi pyodbc
---> Running in bce137040567
Collecting pyodbc
Downloading pyodbc-3.0.10.tar.gz (68kB)
Installing collected packages: pyodbc
Running setup.py install for pyodbc: started
Running setup.py install for pyodbc: finished with status 'error'
Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-fUZvJJ/pyodbc/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-mAZud2-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'pyodbc' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip-build-fUZvJJ
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip-build-fUZvJJ/pyodbc
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip-build-fUZvJJ/pyodbc/src
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=3.0.10 -DPYODBC_UNICODE_WIDTH=4 -DSQL_WCHART_CONVERT=1 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c /tmp/pip-build-fUZvJJ/pyodbc/src/row.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tmp/pip-build-fUZvJJ/pyodbc/src/row.o -Wno-write-strings
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wstrict-prototypes" is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from /tmp/pip-build-fUZvJJ/pyodbc/src/row.cpp:12:
/tmp/pip-build-fUZvJJ/pyodbc/src/pyodbc.h:52:17: error: sql.h: No such file or directory
/tmp/pip-build-fUZvJJ/pyodbc/src/pyodbc.h:53:20: error: sqlext.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /tmp/pip-build-fUZvJJ/pyodbc/src/row.cpp:12:
/tmp/pip-build-fUZvJJ/pyodbc/src/pyodbc.h:69: error: 'IsSet' declared as an 'inline' variable
/tmp/pip-build-fUZvJJ/pyodbc/src/pyodbc.h:69: error: 'DWORD' was not declared in this scope
/tmp/pip-build-fUZvJJ/pyodbc/src/pyodbc.h:69: error: 'DWORD' was not declared in this scope
/tmp/pip-build-fUZvJJ/pyodbc/src/pyodbc.h:69: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
/tmp/pip-build-fUZvJJ/pyodbc/src/pyodbc.h:70: error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token
In file included from /tmp/pip-build-fUZvJJ/pyodbc/src/row.cpp:13:
/tmp/pip-build-fUZvJJ/pyodbc/src/pyodbcmodule.h:36: error: 'HENV' does not name a type
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-fUZvJJ/pyodbc/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-mAZud2-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-fUZvJJ/pyodbc
```

PySide:

```
Step 13 : RUN pip install -i https://pypi.python.org/pypi PySide
---> Running in 5e00a3b909cb
Collecting PySide
Downloading PySide-1.2.4.tar.gz (9.3MB)
Installing collected packages: PySide
Running setup.py install for PySide: started
Running setup.py install for PySide: finished with status 'error'
Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-6DcOnP/PySide/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-xcmRJq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
Removing /tmp/pip-build-6DcOnP/PySide/pyside_package
running install
running build
Python architecture is 64bit
error: Failed to find cmake. Please specify the path to cmake with --cmake parameter.

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-6DcOnP/PySide/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-xcmRJq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-6DcOnP/PySide
```

I have been stuck on this for about 2 days now and cannot figure this out.

Here are some more technique details:

I am host machine runs ubuntu 16, but I am running all these commands from a docker container which has a centos6.6 os.

uname -r:
4.4.0-31-generic

To me it looks like one of the python and c functions definitions/declarations that are meant to match up do not.

Comment: `yum install unixODBC-devel cmake` might help. pip install for pymssql version 2.1.3 worked after `yum install freetds-devel` (centos 6.6, python 2.6.6)

Comment: This did not seem to solve any of the 3 issues.